# How to get a complex type from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

```
 public ObservableCollection<Offer> ModelPersons
    {
        get
        {

            return _persons;
        }


        set
        {
            _persons = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ModelPersons);
        }
    }
```

// How can I get the `ObservableCollection<Person>` from the `Task<ObservableCollection<Person>>`? Right now it's complaining about can not convert source type `Task<Observable<Person>> to Observable<Person>`

```
  private void GetPersonOrders()
    {
        ModelPersons = _service.GetPersonOrders();
    }
```

in Service Class:

```
  private ObservableCollection<Person> _modelPersons;


    public async Task<ObservableCollection<Person>> GetPersonOrders()
    {

        var req =
           WebRequest.Create(
              "http....")
               as HttpWebRequest;

        if (req == null) return null;
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        string message = null;
        if (receiveStream != null)
            using (var readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, encode))
            {
                var result = new char[256];
                int count = await readStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, 256);
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    var value = new String(result, 0, count);
                    message += value;
                    count = await readStream.ReadAsync(result, 0, 256);
                }


                var stringReader = new StringReader(message);
                _modelPersons= new ObservableCollection<Person>();
                var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
                xmlTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
                Person person = null;
                string element = "";
                while (xmlTextReader.Read())
                {
                    if (xmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        element = xmlTextReader.Name;
                    }

                    else if (xmlTextReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                    {
                        switch (element)
                        {
                            case "name":
                                person = new Person { Name = xmlTextReader.Value };
                                _modelPersons.Add(person);
                                break;



                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        return _modelPersons;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use the [`NotifyTaskCompletion` type from my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion).

Then your code will look like this:

```
private INotifyCompletion<ObservableCollection<Offer>> _persons;
public INotifyCompletion<ObservableCollection<Offer>> ModelPersons
{
  get { return _persons; }
  set
  {
    _persons = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => ModelPersons);
  }
}

private void GetPersonOrders()
{
  ModelPersons = NotifyCompletion.Create(_service.GetPersonOrdersAsync());
}
```

And your data binding will change from `ModelPersons` to `ModelPersons.Result`.

Further recommended reading:

- My [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and its followup resources, specifically the [TAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).
- My blog post on [`async` properties](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since your method returns a `Task<ObservableCollection<Person>>` you can get the result of the task via [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

```
private void GetPersonOrders()
{
    ModelPersons = _service.GetPersonOrders().Result;
}
```

Keep in mind however, that accessing the `Result` property will block the calling thread until the task completes, i.e. until you will receive the `WebResponse`.

Another way would be to attach a continuation task to the task returned by your method using [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321474%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The continuation will set the property to the value returned from task.

```
private void GetPersonOrders()
{
    _service.GetPersonOrders()
        .ContinueWith(t => ModelPersons = t.Result);
}
```

Comment: So that will defeat the purpose of using async.

Comment: ObservableCollection<T> does not have .Result as well.

Comment: @Learner, please see the edit about another way of getting the result from the task. Regarding "ObservableCollection<T> does not have .Result as well" - `_service.GetPersonOrders()` returns a `Task` not an `ObservableCollection`; tasks do have a `Result` property.

Comment: Even though the signature return type is Task, it allows ObservableCollection to be returned. _modelPersons is ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Learner, yes, you can return `ObservableCollection<T>` from the method but the callers of your method **won't be able to get it directly**. Something like `ObservableCollection<Person> c = _service.GetPersonOrders();` will not compile.